# How to return a value from C to python from C's PyObject type of functions?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension, python-extensions

I was trying to pass a value by calling C file from python and then return that value from C to python again.

My question is how to do this? Can it possible to use return `Py_BuildValue(a+b)` kind of thing?

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
hello_world(PyObject *self, PyObject *noargs)
{
   int a=5,b=10;

   return Py_BuildValue(a+b); //This is Errorus.
}


static PyMethodDef
module_functions[] = {
    { "hello_world", hello_world, METH_NOARGS, "hello world method" },
    { NULL }
};



PyMODINIT_FUNC
inittesty2(void)
{
    Py_InitModule("testy2", module_functions);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the format of the value:

```
return Py_BuildValue("i", a+b); // "i" for int
```

You can find more format unit [here (`Py_BuildValue` documentation)](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the explicit constructors for integers [`PyInt_FromLong`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong) or [`PyLong_FromLong`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong) instead.

You can find functions like this for any type you can create with `Py_BuildValue` and get a little type safety on top.